# How can I make a QString html-escaped

Tags: c++, html, qt, html-escape

How do I escape/sanitize a QString that contains HTML?

I.e. `showInBroswser(escaped(str)) == showInNotepad(str);`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### Qt 5

Use `QString::toHtmlEscaped()`

```
QString src;
Qstring html = src.toHtmlEscaped();
showInBrowser(html) == showInNotepad(str);
```

Reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toHtmlEscaped

### Qt 4

Use `Qt::escape`.

```
#include <QtGui/qtextdocument.h>

QString src;
Qstring html = Qt::escape(src);
showInBrowser(html) == showInNotepad(str);
```

Reference: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt.html#escape

Comment: Does not work for me because it does not encode german special characters like &auml;
Is there a better function that knows ALL special characters?

Comment: How do you reverse this? i.e., there is no `QString::fromHtmlEscaped()`

Answer (score 8):

Just to bring this answer up with the times, Qt 5.1 has [`QString::toHtmlEscaped()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toHtmlEscaped).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to insert plain text to a QTextEdit you can use:

```
void QTextEdit::insertPlainText ( const QString & text );
```

and, for example, to modify the color :

```
void QTextEdit::setTextColor ( const QColor & c );
```

And similar for the font or other property of the text...

Hope that helps.